# Download audio file from non direct link

Tags: iphone

i want to implement a download manager

lets say there is a form with post method on a site,after clicking the submit button the site will send the post data to its server and a download should start with the content of the response of the form
so what i want is how do i download the data after the user clicks the submit button

any help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

An NSURLRequest is the right choice if there is no API or a simple way to construct the direkt links to create the download links.

You'll have to figure out what kind of Post request is done: Is it a form? Is it an ajax request?

1. Download html with embedded direct link
2. Parse html file, extract information on the post request
3. Create the post request
4. Fire post request and save response, which should be the audio file

Comment: thanks for your answer but the html does not contain any direct link it contains a post method for downloading the audio file

Comment: I see, I've altered my answer.

Comment: but how can i save the response ? not to mention clicking the link will fire the post already (so i think i do not have to send a post request) and iphone movie player tries to play the movie but it gets an error. so i think what i need is a way to stop iphone from firing the movie player and download the post response